# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()

Tags: android, json

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_id);
        new JsonTask().execute("https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8yqrfm08wfdh48/Hotels.txt?dl=0");
    }

class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,String ,List<MovieModels>>{
    @Override
    protected List<MovieModels> doInBackground(String...Params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader =  null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(Params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream= connection.getInputStream();

            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer();
            String line="";
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                buffer.append(line);

            }
            String finaljson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finaljson);
            JSONArray parentArray =parentObject.getJSONArray("Hotels");
            List<MovieModels> modelsList=new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0; i<parentArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject finalobject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                MovieModels models= new MovieModels();
                models.setImage(finalobject.getString("Image"));
                models.setHotel_Name(finalobject.getString("Hotel_Name"));

                modelsList.add(models);

            }

              return modelsList;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModels> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //to do set the data into list


    }
}

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter{

private   List<MovieModels> modelsList;
    private int resource;
  private   LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, List<MovieModels> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        modelsList= objects;
        this.resource=resource;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);

        }
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
        textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(modelsList.get(position).getImage(),imageView);


         textView.setText("Hotel_Name-"+modelsList.get(position).getHotel_Name());

        return convertView;
    }
}}
```

I have an error in the set adapter class, could anyone advise?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: post your MovieModels.java code please

Comment: by the way the first 3 items in the json array are Hotel Name and not Hotel_Name missing the _ so fix it if you want to get all results

Comment: After you fix the JSON as @KostasDrak suggested, Don't ignore the null exception you had, if it for the case the JSON will be broken or changed.

Comment: @Amot, where are you trying to get size() of your list? post your code.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class for your `MovieModels` like this:

```
public class MovieModels(){
    private String imagePath, hotelName;

    public MovieModels(String imagePath, String hotelName){
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
    }

    public String getImagePath(){
        return imagePath;
    }

    public String getHotelName(){
        return hotelName;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath){
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public void setHotelName(String hotelName){
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
    }


}
```

and then modify your `doInBackground()` method like this:

```
@Override
    protected List<MovieModels> doInBackground(String...Params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader =  null;
        List<MovieModels> modelsList=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream= connection.getInputStream();

            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer =new StringBuffer();
            String line="";
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                buffer.append(line);

            }
            String finaljson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finaljson);
            JSONArray parentArray =parentObject.getJSONArray("Hotels");
            for (int i=0; i<parentArray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject finalobject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String image = finalobject.getString("Image");
                String hotelName = finalobject.getString("Hotel_Name");
                modelsList.add(new MovieModels(image, hotelName));
            }

            return modelsList;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

and your `postExecute()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModels> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (result == null) { 
        Log.e("MY APPLICATION", "No result to display");
    }
    Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    //to do set the data into list
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: It may still have the NullPointerException as mentioned in my answer

Comment: forgot the onPost

Comment: I have a MovieModels class ..Whatever you suggest me i did that but code is executing but but doesnot display anything . just blank screen . and I also correct the json file which error u was suggested. plz.. help

Comment: @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModels> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result == null) {
                //todo handle no result
                return;
            }

            Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
           lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I will change only in PostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

You return `null` in your `doInBackground` and then sets it to the adapter.

You have 2 options to solve it:

1. Return an empty Array e.g `return new ArrayList<>();` instead of `return null`
   or
   Check don't set the adapter in case its null. e.g:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<MovieModels> result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       if (result == null) { 
           //todo handle no result
           return;
       }
       Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,result);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);

       //to do set the data into list
   }
   ```

   }

Edit:

In addition, as said in the comments, your JSON Key you are trying to get ("Hotel_Name") is not like the one of the JSON itself (its "Hotel Name" in the JSON). After you fix that you will see the list, though its still important to solve the exception first.

Comment: You still need to fix the JSON though. The key is wrong so it doesn't parse it well

Comment: I  did right key . but after that also doesn't display the ListView.

Comment: Did you check that the list isn't empty?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5j0kar4z211bw8d/hotel_s.txt?dl=0    this is my list url

Comment: Print in the logs the size of your list when you set the adapter, if the size is greater than 0 and still there is nothing in the list. Then, please add you XML files. And try to add @Override to theist count in the adapter with your list.soze()